# How can I change the debug path included in the DWARF info of a binary by the compiler

Tags: debugging, gcc, path, gdb, dwarf

GCC includes the path to the source file that was used to generate an object file in its DWARF debug information (when compiled with -g).

However, GDB's [search rules](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) mean that I have to use the lesser-known `set subsitute-path` if I moved the source-code to a different subdirectory. Alternatively, maybe I want to hide some path information of my source files, of maybe just shorten it.

Does GCC provide an option to change the source path it includes in debug information of a binary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `-fdebug-prefix-map=old_path=new_path` option to GCC.

As far as I can find, LLVM/Clang does not provide an equivalent option.

Comment: This took me hours to find, and wouldn't come up for any search combination of [dwarf, debug, path, pattern, replacement, substitution], so I'm posting it here in the hope of improving its google-juice.

Comment: `rpm` includes a `debugedit` command that does this.  I think it is somewhat hacky (IIRC).  In any case Fedora uses this to rewrite debuginfo paths while building an RPM.